# Microsoft Dynamics CRM performance issue on client side

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am new at the company and we have CRM2011 deployed on the sites and we have agents using our CRM system. On Weekly basis, end users complain that the CRM is running slow on the clients computers. I am beginning to learn about CRM and don't konw much about it.

Does CRM clients side application capture any data or log any information that would help me investigate why CRM is running slow on their computers?

Users clear cached, cookies , temp files on their Internet explorer browser and slowness issue goes away.

How can I further investigate this?

Comment: this question is off topic for stackoverflow. perhaps [sf] might be better?

Comment: There are so many factors that could cause bad performance. Your best bet to identify the bottleneck will be to work your way through all layers. Check page load browser performance. Analyze general server performance metrics. I wasted hours on end to tracing and found out by pure chance that my client was running his production crm on a vm with a single processor core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On Weekly basis, end users complain that the CRM is running slow on
>   the clients computers

You first need to define the specific metrics for "slow" - must be repeatably measurable, not just a user's opinion. There is a big difference between the problem of "when I first launch CRM it takes 30 seconds to load" and "when I save a new Account record it takes 25 seconds" - you must get the problem statements down to these types of specifics. Otherwise, you'll never know where to look and you won't know if you have fixed it.

Now, once you have the specific performance problems you need to determine if CRM - at a baseline in your environment - is performing acceptably. Create a new organization in CRM and create some accounts and contacts during a period of low-load in both the new organization and the current organization. What is the performance difference? Can you account for this performance difference because of plugins executing? Perform updates, assigns, deletes, etc and make the same measurements.

This is where I would start if I knew absolutely nothing about the system and its history. Once I could narrow down the specific performance and I had a control organization - running in the same environment - to use for comparison I would go to Serverfault and post a specific question with all the relevant details (custom entities, workflows/plugins, server config, sql configuration/indexing, workstation setup, network topology, etc.) for each performance issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Nicknow is correct in that you have to get some metrics and figure out if this is truly a client side CRM Outlook performance issue or if it's a server side issue that may be due to poor SQL Server or poor Microsoft CRM Server performance.

If you want to rule out poor network latency as a cause for the performance issues, you can navigate to the Microsoft CRM web site from the web client from http:///tools/diagnostics/diag.aspx (basically just tack on /tools/diagnostics/diag.aspx to the end of the CRM URL) and run the tests from that page, noting that you should be seeing less than 100 ms latencies for better performance and ideally closer to 10 ms or less latencies if on a local area network.  While not as common any more, if your clients have 2 GB of RAM or less or are running with slower single or dual core processors, that will also contribute to slower performance.  Another factor that I didn't see mentioned is that if a user has thousands of emails per Outlook folder or a very large mailbox with GBs of emails, then that may be a bigger contributor to the poor performance as well.

If you wish to investigate and change some performance for the better with regards to the Microsoft CRM Outlook clients, you can refer to this KB article - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2585157, "Slow performance when you use the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 client for Outlook" as it has many registry key values for the various synchronization settings.  In general increasing some of the sync intervals is a good way to boost the performance of the CRM Outlook clients as well as to reduce the overall load on the SQL Server since it will then have less queries to deal with so frequently (especially if you are in an organization with over 100 concurrent or more Microsoft CRM users).  If you don't want to bother with all of the registry keys, you can just make some changes to the CRM Outlook client synchronization times that I've copied below that are at the bottom of the article above.

"Additionally, you can also try to increase the Outlook synchronization interval. By default, this interval is set to 15 minutes. To increase the internal, follow these steps: 1.Open the CRM Web Client.
2.Click  Settings, click Administration, and then click System Settings. 
3.Click the Outlook tab, and then examine the Minimum time between synchronizations option.

A Microsoft Dynamics CRM user can adjust the synchronization value for this server setting up to the minimum value that is defined in the user's personal Microsoft Dynamics CRM options in Outlook. To update the Outlook minimum value, follow these steps: 1.Open Microsoft Outlook 2010. 
2.Click File, click CRM, and then click Options.
3.Under the Synchronization tab, update the value for the Synchronize the CRM items in my Outlook folder every 'x' minutes option.
"

The following blog article has many good items to check with regards to the CRM Outlook client performance as well as server side performance items (I've copied some of the client side items to check here)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ritesh_ranjan/archive/2013/11/21/dynamics-crm-outlook-client-performance-troubleshooting-and-optimizations-guide.aspx

"Isolating Outlook performance issues:
•What is the update rollup installed for CRM outlook clients?
•What do we mean by performance issues? Are we talking about overall outlook performance or anything in specific?
•Have we defined any performance benchmark? If not, it’s not too late.
•What exactly happens when you notice the performance issue? A complete understanding of the issue with proper description.
•Do we get any errors or just the outlook becomes sluggish?
•How many concurrent users are accessing CRM at the same time when the issue happens?
•Does this issue happen with all the users at the same time or is it random?
•Does this happen with a specific entity within CRM? If yes, let’s drill down on that entity first.
•Are we talking about performance issues as soon as we launch the outlook client or does it happen all across the time during its use?
•How is the performance of the CRM Server at the same time when this issue happens?
•How is the overall performance of Dynamics CRM over web client?
•Does faulty users have multiple mailboxes configured on their outlook?
•What is the service pack level for outlook?

Note: It is always better to have the latest service packs and update rollups installed with proper testings in your Dev./UAT/Test environment.

"

If you still have issues after going through these items, it would be good to dig into this deeper with your Microsoft CRM Partner, Microsoft CRM support, or if you are a Microsoft premier customer, to work with the Microsoft CRM PFE team.